# Setting a Range with a variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have created a for loop to detect where does an empty value appears in range "E7:AB7". Once done that I want to create a Range from E7 to that empty value so it can copy and paste the data from a Master Sheet only within that range.

For example if it detects an empty value in X7 then the Range must be ("E7:X7").
Here is a sample of the code:

```
Sub Macro5()
For Each cell In Worksheets("Proof").Range("E7:AB7")
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        Dim Cval As Range
        Set Cval = Worksheets("Proof").Range(cell.Address)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
    Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A3:AG5000").AdvancedFilter Action:= _
        xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("E7" & ":" & Cval), Unique:=False    'Here is where the dynamic range exists  
End Sub
```

Someone have an idea on how to apply it to the Range function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please play a little with the code below.

```
    Private Sub Test()
    
        Dim Rng         As Range            ' dynamic range in row 7
        
        With Worksheets("Proof")
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(7, "E"), .Cells(7, "E").End(xlToRight))
    '       use the line below to include the blank in the range
    '        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(7, "E"), .Cells(7, "E").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1))
        End With
'        Debug.Print Rng.Address
        Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A3:AG5000").AdvancedFilter _
                              Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                              CopyToRange:=Rng, _
                              Unique:=False         'Here is where the dynamic range exists
    End Sub
```

`Set Rng = .Cells(7, "E").End(xlToRight)` sets a range of a single cell, defined as the last used cell before a blank cell, looking from E7 to the right. A range from E7 to that cell therefore excludes the blank cell itself. Therefore, in your example, if E7 itself is blank the code will crash or maybe set a range D7:E7, neither of which you want. Therefore you may prefer to include the blank cell in the range as, in fact, your code suggested.

Your code `CopyToRange:=Range("E7" & ":" & Cval)` has two flaws, at least one of which proved fatal. One is that you calculate the range at the time of using it. In my code the range is prepared before use so that you can check its address before you feed it to the filter. The other flaw is that you don't specify the sheet on which your range is supposed to exist. Therefore it will be on the ActiveSheet which could be any sheet at all. My code, you may argue, doesn't specify the worksheet, either. That isn't entirely true. Try `Debug.Print Rng.Worksheet.Name`.